# grep block of lines

Tags: sed, grep

I want to `grep` every block of lines that has starting line with "CK \" at the end of line and ending line that has "D \" at the end of line, I can use sed/awk/grep etc.

So far i have tried following with no luck:

```
$ sed -e '/CK \\$/,/D \\$/' file | more
```

Here is the example of one of the blocks.

```
 pcs_dual_logic/e3bis_chbist_jj/e3bis_ch_ptn_gen_cur_st_reg_1_/CK \
  pcs_dual_logic/e3bis_chbist_jj/e3bis_ch_ptn_gen_cur_st_reg_1_/Q \
  pcs_dual_logic/e3bis_chbist_jj/U341/X \
  pcs_dual_logic/e3bis_chbist_jj/U331/X \
  pcs_dual_logic/e3bis_chbist_jj/U70/X \
  pcs_dual_logic/e3bis_chbist_jj/U487/X \
 pcs_dual_logic/est_jje3bis_ch_ptn_gen_e3bis_random_data_gen_random_data_reg_6_/D \
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sed '/CK \\$/,/D \\$/!d' file | more
```